# Questions Eligible for Asker Deletion - Policy Change

Tags: feature-request

The policy regarding an asker's deletion of their own question is:

> Users can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> - has zero answers
> - only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes

What is the purpose/reasoning of allowing the asker to delete the question under the second qualifying condition? Someone could've provided a useful answer and the asker still possesses absolute and unchecked discretionary ability to delete the question.

This policy invites abuse and should be modified where only the first condition qualifies a question deletion without the necessity of peer review.

Comment: I wonder if "no upvotes" means "a net score of zero".  As for the "useful" answer - there may be a small window in which another user that would deem it useful doesn't see it and doesn't upvote it, but I would presume that all useful answers are indeed upvoted by those with the privilege.

Comment: I agree that all useful answers _should_ be upvoted, especially by the asker if it helped them in any way, but maybe newer users think once their problem is solved the question doesn't serve any further purpose.

Comment: @Makoto That would be an incorrect presumption, witnessed by browsing the list of zero-score answers. The number of [zero score accepted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+score%3A0+isaccepted%3Ayes) is close to 1M. Apparently those are useful, but no one upvoted them.