# Asker can delete question as soon as an answer is received, which also deletes answer. Design/flaw?

Tags: feature-request

I encountered a situation where I put effort down in answering a question, and saw it be deleted as soon as I posted the answer.

According to the [rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions):

> Users can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> - has zero answers
> - only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes

However, it will *always* be the case that a question with an answer will at some point have an answer with no upvotes.

Without restricting the second rule by a minimum elapsed time, it is open for anyone to delete their question, even though it might very well be useful to the community.

My initial reaction was to assume self ignorance and ask for the rationale behind the second rule, but that has already been done [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272211/questions-eligible-for-asker-deletion-policy-change).

So, as a lowly ranked user such as myself without the ability to open closed questions (for good reason), I'm curious as to what the intended result is. The rules are clearly susceptible to removal of useful answers by new users (whose only contribution is asking the question).

Also, and more importantly, deleted questions are not visible by users with `< 10 000` reputation. and *neither are the answers*. Which means that unless I cached the page, *even my own answer* has been deleted, with no trace.

IMO, this certainly shouldn't be the case.

Comment: You don't have a link to the deleted post? Also not from http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/1731448

Comment: For low ranking users, the link you provided can be used to retrieve the link and title of the question that was deleted.  However, users with less than 10.000 reputation are shown a `Page not found` when attempting following the question link. So to answer your question: Yes, I do. But, it doesn't help solve the problem. (I also have the cached page. But this isn't about me and my removed answer ;) )

Comment: In [this related post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260692/how-to-handle-users-deleting-their-questions-after-receiving-an-answer) it is suggested to flag for a moderator. And if you share the link some of the high-reps here can have a look if it is worth keeping.

Comment: See also: [Can't access my own answer on a deleted question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287028/cant-access-my-own-answer-on-a-deleted-question) This needs to be fixed.  If you want to get the text for a specific answer, i'm sure someone with 10k rep will be happy to get it for you.

Comment: @rene I agree that flagging for moderator review seems like the right way to handle it. But, how would a user flag a question he has no access to? Is there a general "report to moderators" functionality that I'm unaware of? I was (seemingly) able to flag it, but only because I hadn't closed the tab with the question.

Comment: Flag on any post of that user or a post of your own, or post on meta which you did. In all cases clearly explain what needs to be done, including links to the post it concerns.

Comment: That is all perfectly reasonable. A combination of all the suggestions answers my question: 1. Get link to deleted question from list-of-deleted-answers list (I wasn't aware this existed until now).  2. Report to moderator through a flag, on a meta post, if nothing else.

Comment: I had this experience recently and did exactly that, the question (homework) was reinstated, and an upvote magically appeared on my answer so it couldn't happen again. Homework askers sometimes feel it should not be obvious to either a teacher searching, or classmates getting an easy answer as well :-)

Comment: Jon Skeet’s answers get upvoted before he posts them.

Answer (score 61):

I *think* you're suggesting that when someone posts an answer to the question, the OP shouldn't be able to delete the question (and therefore the answer) within a short period of time (say, 15 minutes). If so, I'd agree, that makes good sense. I've had it happen a few times: The question is worth answering, I spend time answering it, and moments after I post my answer the OP deletes it. (I never put it down to them doing it on purpose, just poor timing.)

**Suggestion**:

I'd suggest that the OP **can** delete the question if

1. The question's score is 0 or lower (at least as many downvotes as upvotes), and
2. Any of the following is true:

   1. The question has no answers
   2. The question has only one answer, that answer's score is 0 (same number of downvotes as upvotes) or negative (more downvotes than upvotes), and the answer was posted more than 15 minutes ago *(e.g., the subject of your original feature request)*
   3. I'd also add a third condition: The question has only answers with a negative score (more downvotes than upvotes), even if more than one answer. This would let OPs delete questions they can't currently delete, I think, but if they want to delete a poor question with only poor answers, that seems like a useful thing we should let them do.

When calculating the answer's score for points 2.2 and 2.3, as [Pshemo points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289338/asker-can-delete-question-as-soon-as-an-answer-is-received-which-also-deletes-a/289353?noredirect=1#comment172581_289353), the OP's votes should be ignored.

Comment: How about adding condition that OP votes on answers should not count into *score* used in tests to prevent votes manipulation just to delete question?

Comment: @Pshemo: That's a very, very good point.

Comment: I think that the probability that there's useful bit of information out of two (-1 score) answers to someone outscores the benefit from deleting them all together. (Talking about the third paragraph.) Or you think that what I said is it too subjective?

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: Not too subjective, but I think that if the community has downvoted two answers *and* the OP wants to delete the question, the preponderance of the evidence is that that's an okay thing to do. :-)

Comment: ` if they want to delete a question with only poor answers, that seems like a useful thing we should let them do` - I don't think this is sufficient. Unless the _question_ is poor too, the question remains a useful contribution and only awaits a useful answer.

Comment: @RegEdit: A restriction related to votes on the *question* would probably make sense, yeah.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No complains. +1

Comment: I'd consider simplifying 2 and 3, into just "the question has no answers with score >= 0" (ignoring votes of the OP, as you've already suggested). I  don't want the OP to be able to delete a question once it has an answer, unless that answer is determined to be crap (score < 0).

Comment: @Matt: I was tying to avoid changing too much (allowing the OP to delete questions with multiple answers with a score of 0).

Answer (score 4):

This has happened to me a few times too, and I found it very irritating.

They should be able to push the delete button and it should say "your question will be deleted if the answer doesn't have > 0 score within 15 minutes".  The OP's vote shouldn't count in that calculation.